# Multiple API Keys fcm and google map

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, firebase-cloud-messaging

In my app, I used FCM and Google Maps. I have 2 API Keys. Android does not allow me to use them together.

How can I use one API Key for the both of them?

Comment: Do note that the FCM Server Key should only be kept on your server side (hence the *Server* key) and never to be disclosed to the public and not to be included in your client app. I'm not so sure as to what you mean by *Android does not allow me to use them together* though. FCM and Google Maps is a separate service.

Answer (score 1):

For Maps API, you need to add the following line in your manifest:

```
   <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="YOUR_API_KEY"/>
```

And for FCM the key, it can be seen in your Firebase Console in the Cloud Messaging tab.

Comment: FCM API key is added in same way, then how do we differentiate which one to use.